# Playing imdb video inside MPMediaPlayback not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video

I fetch the video url from imdb of a trailer, like:

```
http://video-http.media-imdb.com/MV5BMjM2OTAxNDA2Nl5BMTFeQW1wNF5BbWU3MDYwMDA4OTY@.mp4?Expires=1347051666&Signature=4OPreoHNu1wcEMX2UIkKYvnu1y7r9NG6qoLf5w1egm7D-5UVSZI6KAZkxX5BA9h7Zj88LZEEWowBbgdh2CC8Zdr2syj1IL4Ncew~rqgLvuBRkwbHyIJzag2CBXEblmAHkMR3NRoOxy93iUXMvZrNj2pnxuYjF9Bf9AODrBxmUdc_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAILW5I44IHKUN2DYA
```

by adding the rest of the code:

```
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL]; 
    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 270)]; 
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
```

I only get this error (in the simlator, not tried on device):

```
Error getting audio input device sample rate
```

Regards
Mirza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try bellow code

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Url"];

    mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    [[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```

Comment: thx for answer, its still the same: Error getting audio input device sample rate: '!obj'